# Cookies obtained for HTTP Endpoint 1 needs to be sent as the Header in the HTTP Rest Endpoint 2(GET) .Its Working in Postman but not in Azure LogicApp

Tags: azure, cookies, azure-logic-apps

So , I have a required where I need to first run the Authentication URL (this would give me the cookies). These cookies needs to be sent in the Main GET Rest API Endpoint which ideally should give me the JSON message in the response body.

The above scenario is working fine in the Postman bit in the Azure Logic App , it seems the cookies been supplied in the Endpoint 2 is either not getting picked up or getting acknowledged.

[image]

So here, I extracted the cookies value from "HTTP Authentication" and now I am trying to supply the same in the HTTP request (GET)

[image]

[image]

But I am not getting the expected JSON in the response output probably because of the supplied issue. Does anyone has any idea on the same ?

Below is the logic app code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IigvO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvW4s.png)
[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZGPd.png)

Comment: Are you saying the expression where you’re trying to get the returned cookie isn’t working or logic apps in general?

Comment: Can you help us with the schema of your `Parse_JSON` and also where the logic app is failing to meet your requirement.

Comment: So , the scenario is:
I have two URL (provided to me by the different teams). First URL is for authentication (which has username and password) and from this URL , the cookies needs to be picked up and used in the second URL (Main GET RestAPI).

Now , from the postman , if in case I directly run the second endpoint without first hitting the authentication url , HTML format data would appear in the response (while the expected is json format which would be received only after the cookies from the first endpoint is used.)

Comment: Now in the logic app , in the second HTTP request , I am receiving the HTML characters even after using the HTTP Authentication step on the above action . Therefore , I assume that the cookies I am passing in the second request is not working probably .

Comment: @AniMathur Can you try adding your cookie only in the Cookie field instead of adding at header and also would like to know if this was working while you are trying to provide cookie from postman.